# Find domain of a user

Tags: powershell, dns, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I would like a powershell script to find the domain of an user.

I tried with `Get-ADUser <user> -Properties *`
It shows the `domain(CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=nam,DC=nsroot,DC=net)`. But I want it to display on the domain because I have a huge list of users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
Get-ADUser <user> -Properties * |
Select *,@{l='Domain';e={ $_.canonicalname.split('/')[0] } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well..there is the userprincipalname property but a lot of times it is blank. You could do something like this

```
(get-aduser -filter *).SamAccountName | % {$_.Insert(0,'test\')}
```

Just change 'test\' to your domain name

Answer (score 0):

Pick what properties you want and modify this:

```
$Domain = Get-ADDomain | select -expandproperty NetBIOSName

Get-ADUser <USERID OR -Filter *> -Properties DisplayName | select samAccountName, DisplayName, @{n="Domain";e={$Domain}} | Export-Csv Users1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Just in case someone else is looking for this in the future...